# Can I change the Path of a Stellar history archive?

Tags: stellar-core, stellar-sdk, stellar-laboratory

In `stellar-core.cfg` (stellar config file) we need to define a **history** **configuration**.

The default setting is `mkdir="mkdir -p /tmp/stellar-core/history/vs/{0}"`. Can I change this directory location, or is the default location compulsory to use?

Answer (score 1):

You can put it wherever you want. In fact `/tmp` is the worst place to use since that is a **temporary** folder and everything in it may and will be wiped on every reboot on most systems. I'd put it to `/etc/something` or if you use the docker container it should probably better be in the persistent folder (afaik `/opt/stellar/something`).